# How to count when value in column change from any number to 10 by groupby one day data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with three columns , time , A and flag.

1. first apply groupby function to group in days ,and then check in column flag how many times changes to 10 and for how long time remains 10.

input:

```
                  Time  flag
0  2019-02-14 00:00:10     1
1  2019-02-14 00:00:16     3
2  2019-02-14 00:00:21     4
3  2019-02-14 00:00:27    10
4  2019-02-14 00:00:32    10
5  2019-02-15 00:00:37     1
6  2019-02-15 00:00:43     0
7  2019-02-15 00:00:48    10
8  2019-02-15 00:00:54    10
9  2019-02-15 00:00:59    10
```

output:

```
    group_start_time 1   group_end_time   count_change_to_10    minimum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10    Maximum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10

2019-02-14 00:00:10    2019-02-14 00:00:32       1              2              2              2 

2019-02-15 00:00:37    2019-02-15 00:00:59       1              3               3              3
```

Comment: what is difference between `count_change_to_10` and `_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10` ? Is possible change data for different counts per rows?

Comment: @jezrael , sorry in question was little mistake i modify , count_change_to_10  mean how many times value changes to 10 ,  here in my data it will be 1 Times change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregation:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

m = df['flag'].eq(10)

g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]
df['count'] = g.map(g.value_counts())


df = df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.date).agg(group_start_time_1=('Time','first'),
                                        group_end_time_1=('Time','last'),
                                        count_change_to_10 =('count','nunique'),
                                        minimum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10=('count', 'min'),
                                        Maximum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10=('count', 'max'))
print (df)
            group_start_time_1    group_end_time_1  count_change_to_10  \
Time                                                                     
2019-02-14 2019-02-14 00:00:10 2019-02-14 00:00:32                   1   
2019-02-15 2019-02-15 00:00:37 2019-02-15 00:00:59                   1   

            minimum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10  \
Time                                                          
2019-02-14                                              2.0   
2019-02-15                                              3.0   

            Maximum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10  
Time                                                         
2019-02-14                                              2.0  
2019-02-15                                              3.0
```

EDIT: Solution for pandas <0.25 is with dictionary in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with dictionary:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

m = df['flag'].eq(10)
#consecutive groups only by mask
g = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m]
#counter only matched values by mask
df['count'] = g.map(g.value_counts())

df = df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.date).agg({'Time':['first','last'],
                                         'count':['nunique','min','max']})
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

d = {'Time_first':'group_start_time_1',
     'Time_last':'group_end_time_1',
     'count_nunique':'count_change_to_10',
     'count_min':'minimum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10',
     'count_max':'Maximum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10'}

cols = ['Maximum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10',
        'Maximum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10']
df = df.rename(columns=d)
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
         Time  group_start_time_1    group_end_time_1  count_change_to_10  \
0  2019-02-14 2019-02-14 00:00:10 2019-02-14 00:00:32                   1   
1  2019-02-15 2019-02-15 00:00:37 2019-02-15 00:00:59                   1   

   minimum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10  \
0                                              2.0   
1                                              3.0   

   Maximum_duration_of_each_group_value_remains_10  
0                                                2  
1                                                3
```